# execute a programman REPL with perl

Tags: perl, testing, read-eval-print-loop, test-more

I have a C program, and I must be write tests with Perl and Test::More. 
But, my C program is a REPL. 
This is a brief example the this running:
COMPILE

```
clang main.c -o database.db
./database.db
```

INITIAL APPARENCE

```
db>
```

EXECUTE COMMAND IN THIS

```
db> insert 1 guilherme
```

... well ... this is a program running.

Now, I have a tests in Perl and it is this:
TEST IF COMPILE OK

```
ok(&compile(), "Compile is sucess");
sub compile {
    my $compile = "clang $SRC_PATH/main.c -o test.db";
    system $compile;
    return -e "test.db";
}
```

Now, I needed send commands after executing the program in C.

```
system "./test.db"
... parse commands
```

But every time executing program with the perl `system ...` the test lock:

```
3 warnings generated.

ok 1 - Compile is sucess
```

the first test runed, but the second tests not running.

Somebody help me a execute program REPL in the Perl script or other language??

[project_link](https://github.com/GuilhermeGiacomoSimoes/a_simple_experimental_database)

Comment: instead of system maybe try popen so you can send input to the program.

Comment: What does this have to do with c?  It's a perl question.  It's ready to deadlock when using popen so ensure you have timeouts.  Also, check out the wonderful world of test anything protocol (TAP).

Comment: The testing program needs to keep sending input to another running program.  One way is to use the `IPC::Run` module, which can do that.  You'd have to play with it a little to learn how to use it but it is not too bad and it is a very useful module.  There are other libraries as well.

Comment: expect would be my choice, but a quick search of cpan leads to https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Expect